# How to make a transaction only persist objects that are referred inside the transaction method?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

My web application uses Spring (4.2.9), Spring Data (3.2.5), JPA, Hibernate (4.3.8), and MS SQL Server (2014). Here is the flow in a controller method:

```
ObjectA = service.getObjectAById(some_id);
o.setUpdate(new Date()); //for temporary need.
service.createObjectBAndSaveIt(new ObjectB());
```

Here are two related methods in the service layer:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public ObjectA getObjectAById(Long id) {
   //load ObjectA from database
}

@Override
public void createObjectBAndSaveIt(Long id) {
  //create and save ObjectB
}
```

Please note that ObjectA and ObjectB have no relationship, directly or indirectly. ObjectA has a version field as follows:

```
@Version
private Long version = 1L;
```

It is noticed that when above web flow is executed, the version number of ObjectA increases by 1, even though it is NOT referred or used in `service.createObjectBAndSaveIt`. Based on what I know, Hibernate does dirty-check and saves OjbectA when executing `service.createObjectBAndSaveIt`. I dont want this default behavior. How can I make the system ONLY persist the objects (such as ObjectB) that show up inside the transactinal method? Any pointer or example would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you update/creation of object B uses data from object A, this behavior is exactly what you need, otherwise you could have read skew.

Comment: @GionJh, thanks for chimining in! As shown in the code, creating and saving ObjectB is totally independent of ObjectA. What do you mean by "read skew"?

Comment: It's a side effects of cuncurrent transactions writing and reading same data, you can avoid it with optimistic locking.google it.

Comment: If they are independent you don't need it..I can only say that spring data is the player here..but not knowing it in depth I cannot help you further

Comment: GionJh, thanks for chiming in. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses transaction propagation required by default. Try to explicitly annotate your methods with `@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` for methods that deal with data that you want to have persisted (in this case Object B) and use `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` for non-write data (in this case Object A).

**Spring docs states that:**

> The default @Transactional settings are as follows:
>
> Propagation setting is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED. Isolation level is
>   ISOLATION_DEFAULT. Transaction is read/write.

Comment: @guihebl, thanks for the info! I will look into this and test it out, and report back. Thanks, again!

Comment: Hi @guilhbel, I looked at this, and I am not sure how Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW can help. Basically, ObjectA is already loaded via `readOnly = true`. It is used only in the flow of the web controller. It is modified in the flow temporarily, and I dont want to persist such change. However, creating and saving ObjectB makes the change to ObjectA persist, which is not what I want. I want 'service.createObjectBAndSaveIt' only persist the new ObjectB instance.

Comment: @curious1 are you using JPA or have CascadeType.ALL annotated on the relation between objectA and objectB ? Perhaps that might be causing the auto merge of ObjectA, if you're using JPA try detaching object A from the persistence context, invoking void detach(java.lang.Object entity) before persisting objectB

Comment: thanks for followup with me! As indicated in the original post, there is not relationship (reference) between ObjectA and ObjectB, directly or indirectly. ObjectA is never passed to or used in `service.createObjectBAndSaveIt`. I dont want changes to other objects modified in the web flow and outside `service.createObjectBAndSaveIt` get persisted because of inovke of this method. I am not sure whether such auto-persist is the default behavior of JPA/Hibernate. If yes, I hope to change it.